# White Space at the bottom of the Page in FireFox

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, firefox, internet

I am using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise for Internet Facing website. It is working fine in all browser other than FireFox. In firefox it show extra white space at the bottom the page. When page load it have background image with cover as background-size but it will scroll and show white space in bottom.

So for inspection I put below CSS to see where space coming from

```
*{ border: 1px solid red; }
```

Now once page load and it start showing red border and when I go to fire bug and disable above CSS, it will remove white space and I cannot scroll which is correct behaviour. So I feel that space is coming from JavaScript dynamically and space also coming in top of the page also.

Can somebody tell me what can be issue. Is it coming from init.js or core.js ?

Comment: Are you using a custom master page?

Comment: Yes, I have converted my HTML page to Master Page

Comment: I've seen this behavior when a customized ribbon/banner is not the same height as the default.

Comment: any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a custom ribbon?

Comment: @ErinL No I am not using ribbon in anonymous but it will appear when I am logged in

Comment: How are you hiding the ribbon for anonymous? Do you have a master page that has no ribbon, have you hidden in using css, or using javascript?

Comment: @ErinL Actually I generated Master page from HTML page. And this HTML page does not have ribbon

Comment: Have you tried anything from this question? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89032/scrollbar-appears-while-page-is-loading-sharepoint-2013